# SQL ''Field" = {variable}' Select by attribute arcpy

Tags: sql, arcpy

I am trying to run a select by attribute where I select all points where "Id" field matches the numeric variable point_id. point_id = 375.

I've tried a few quotation styles and using curly brackets to call my variable. I'm not the most familiar with SQL queries and get an error saying the positional argument follows the keyword string. I have also tried storing my SQL as a variable on it's own called a whereClause and get the same error.

[First attempt code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuNpG.png)

```py
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_layer_or_view = deer,
                                       selection_type = "NEW_SELECTION",
                                       f'"Id"={point_id}')
```

[Second attempt code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSA1o.png)

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a Python issue, not related to ArcGIS or SQL.

You are trying to pass three arguments. For the first two arguments you're using *keyword argument* (explicitly specifying the argument name: **in_layer_or_view =** deer), but for the third one you're using *positional argument* (letting python assign the value to the appropriate argument based on the order of the arguments).

The execption you're getting is telling you that you can't mix the two types this way. Once you started using keyword arguments in the function call, all of the next argument must be passed with their explicit name too.

To fix this, you can use positional argument for all of the arguments (i.e. not specifing argument names at all), or alternatively keep specifing the names for all of the rest of the arguments.

In your case, this should work:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_layer_or_view=deer,
                                        selection_type="NEW_SELECTION",
                                        where_clause=f'"Id"={point_id}')
```

or alternatively:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(deer,
                                        "NEW_SELECTION",
                                        f'"Id"={point_id}')
```